# Issue with visualizing a field in Kibana even when elasticsearch has its mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have elasticsearch mapping which lists a field but when trying to visualize in kibana it doesnt list that field. Moreover i can see that field under 'popular' section of Discover page.

i see some note like:
"This field is present in your elasticsearch mapping but not in any documents in the search results. You may still be able to visualize or search on it."

What does this mean and how can i visualize a mapped field.

Comment: The version of Kibana that you're using? Could be [helpful](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2180)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mean that you have a mapping but you don't have documents, you don't have data,so you need to index data to elasticsearch index

Comment: It got Resolved. I deleted the old Index and Create a new one, now it shows as properly.